# Django: How to check if something is an email without a form

Tags: python, django, emailfield

I have HTML form to post in Django View and because of some constraints, it's easier for me to do the `validation` without the usual Django form classes.

My only reason to use Django Forms is Email Field(s) that are entered.

Is there any function to check if something is an `email` or I have to use the `EmailField` to check and validate it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the following

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django import forms

...
if request.method == "POST":
    try:
        validate_email(request.POST.get("email", ""))
    except forms.ValidationError:
        ...
```

assuming you have a `<input type="text" name="email" />` in your form

Answer (score 6):

You can use the validate_email() method from django.core.validators:

```
>>> from django.core import validators
>>> validators.validate_email('test@example.com')
>>> validators.validate_email('test@examplecom')
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/Users/jasper/Sites/iaid/env/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/core/validators.py", line 155, in __call__
    super(EmailValidator, self).__call__(u'@'.join(parts))
  File "/Users/jasper/Sites/iaid/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 44, in __call__
    raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)
ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid e-mail address.']
```

Comment: If someone wants to customise the error message, it can be done with writing `validators.validate_email.message = 'My custom Error message'`

Comment: EmailValidator(message='My custom Error message')('test@examplecom')

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
```

#### Using Python

```
def check_email(email) -> bool:
    # The regular expression
    pat = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'
    if re.match(pat, email):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Using regular expression to validate the email

### Using Django but this raise a validation error

```
from django.core import validators
validators.validate_email("test@gmail.com")
```